# PHP header redirect that maintains query parameters?

Tags: php, redirects, url-parameters

I am experimenting with the PHP redirect http://www.phpjunkyard.com/tutorials/php-redirect.php.

Specifically the 301 redirect to create a self correcting URL to help with typos - there's a unique ID in the URL as well that needs to be correct for it to work.

Can I still allow for analytics tracking parameters e.g. `tracking=yes` ?

Currently the rewrite strips this out.

Comment: It's not mentioned in your linked article, but the `header()` function has a 3rd argument where you can specify the HTTP status code (ie. 301). See the PHP Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to append all the query parameters you would want to use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to extract them from the current URL, you would then append this to the location of the redirect:

```
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

If you only wanted to pass certain variables, you could get them individually and then append them in a similar way:

```
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com?tracking=".$_GET["tracking"]);
```

Comment: Just to note, values in the `$_GET` array are already URL decoded. So these should be validated and possibly `urlencode()`d before building the URL. In fact it is advisable to validate everything you are 'passing back' to the URL.